# How to avoid watch list variable to collapse on value change in Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, watch

I would like to avoid that the watch window collapse my list variable content on value change during  the process of my application in debug mode. I don't know if i'm really clear, see pictures below:

Collapsed:

[image]

Expended:

[image]

I would like to see the content of my list and let the content of my list expanded even if a string of my list change. Is there a way to lock the watch window?

Comment: what is the type of "masterFile.FileContent" in your screenshots above?

Answer (score 6):

As @JasonH mentioned, list will stay expanded while variable references same object and watch will show modified element in red color. List will collapse when you assign new reference to a variable. I am not aware of any option to change this behavior.

As an alternative, you can pin items in a list you are interested in. Or you can pin all items. In this you will get list expanded event if reference changes. But It will be available only in this concrete tab. Here is an example and picture of each step:

```
var ints = new [] {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
ints[1] = "3";
ints = new[] { "1" };
```

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]

Comment: I can't test it at the moment. How you can "pin items"?

Comment: @PawełAudionysos, you need to hoover variable in debug. You will see a pin icon: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/04/08/visual-studio-tip-2-pin-your-data-tips/.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to 'pinning a watch item open' is no, you cannot.

First, this option is just not available in VS but you can suggest it at [Visual Studio User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide) if you feel that it would help you and others.

Second, and this gets a bit complicated but follow with me...
If the watch item goes out of scope, it will collapse.  If the watch item is re-initialized (which in a way kind of takes it out of scope for a moment) it will also collapse.  If you have a watch item (complex object) and you start changing its properties and/or fields, you will see that they (the properties and fields) will change but the watch item (object) does not collapse.

I hope this helps.